# Resume from suspend causes reboot

Tags: release-hera, suspend, grub, microsoft-windows

I recently stuck a second hard drive with Windows 10 installed in my system. Ever since, suspend is not working correctly in Elementary OS. The computer appears to suspend normally, but when I wake it up (for example by hitting any key on the keyboard) it just reboots - I get the BIOS splash screen, GRUB menu, disk encryption prompt (seems slower than usually at this step) etc up to login.

Very annoying and I don't really know where to start, seems like there are lots of Linux suspend issues out there including on 18.04, possible Kernel bugs, etc. but all the troubleshooting ideas I see involve laptops and power management issues. I had no problems until I installed another drive (with Windows 10 preinstalled) and ran update-grub in Elementary. Dual booting seems to work as expected and suspend works fine in Windows. But ever since I've had this rather inconvenient issue.

Obviously this may not be an Elementary problem per se but I figured I'd start here. Not even sure where I'd find the relevant logs. The only thing that shows up in /var/log/syslog after suspend and right before it starts rebooting is `systemd-modules-load[552]: Inserted module 'lp'` Apparently this is something to do with parallel ports...doesn't really give me any clues, I'm too young to really know what a parallel port is and I'm not all that young. If this is causing the crash, that really would be too funny. (The lp module seems to load fine on reboot after the crash.)

I'm on 5.1.7 Hera, kernel 5.4.0, NVIDIA GPU with proprietary drivers.